# Convert json to long format table using jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

Given an array of JSON objects, all having the same key names (key1, key2, key3) and just one key (key3) whose value is an array, how can it be converted to a long format table?

**Input:**

```
[
  { "key1": "A",
    "key2": 1,
    "key3" : ["aaa", "bbb"]
  },
  { "key1": "B",
    "key2": 2,
    "key3" : ["ccc", "ddd"]
  }
]
```

**Desired output:**

| key1 | key2 | key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | aaa |
| A | 1 | bbb |
| B | 2 | ccc |
| B | 2 | ddd |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.[]| ([.key1,.key2] + (.key3[]|[.])) | @csv
```